# Apache2 on Raspberry pi 3 - cannot install WSGI module

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I have a Raspberry pi 3 with Raspbian Stretch with desktop.
What I need to do is install an Apache server and the WSGI module in order to run a flask app.

I could install Apache without issues: `sudo apt-get install apache2`

but as soon as I tried to install WSGI with `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi` 
I got the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-wsgi (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-wsgi
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I wanted to check if the package was there, so I typed `dpkg -l libapache2-mod-wsgi` and the package seemed to be there.

Doing `apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES` my package wasn't in the list.

I did some research and found that there is/was a known bug and the suggested fix was to go to /etc/apache2/mods-available/ and create a wsgi.conf file with this content:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Following the instructions I found, you then should creat esome symbolic links:

```
cd  /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ && ln -s ../mods-available/wsgi.load
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ && ln -s ../mods-available/wsgi.conf
```

restart Apache and it should work... but of course it did not.

Apache could not restart for some error and the only thing I could do was uninstall it, clean config files and restart.

Any idea?? Thank you for you suggestions!

Comment: Have you made a `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt full-upgrade` and `sudo systemctl reboot`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ingo

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo systemctl reboot
```

this sequence seems to fix the problem I had with the wsgi module.